# How to use string interpolation in html "value" attribute

Tags: angular

I use the below to generate date in component.ts file:

```
this.myDate=new Date();
```

And try to use in html form value field.But nothing is loaded.I have tried both the below syntax but not succesful

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="date" value={{this.myDate}} name="created" ngModel>

<input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="date" [value]=[this.myDate] name="created" ngModel>
```

One more issue is that my json file is upadted with only empty string after add operation

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the right date format for the input type datetime that is  `="2017-06-01T08:30"`

in the component.ts

```
formatted_date:string;

ngOnInit(){
//your code...
this.formatted_date = this.myDate.toISOString();
this.formatted_date.slice(0,16);
}
```

In the template.html (change the type to datetime-local beacuse datetime is Obsolete [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime))

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="date" value="{{formatted_date}}" name="created">
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you remove the `ngModel` directive (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subclass-dependency-injection-bwkysq)):

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="date" value="{{myDate}}" name="created">
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="date" [value]="myDate" name="created">
```

An alternative is to set the value with `[ngModel]` (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subclass-dependency-injection-qvnppp)):

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="date" [ngModel]="myDate" name="created">
```

Comment: I get only mm/did/yy in date field

Comment: Check if the data is correct with `this.myDate = new Date(); console.log(this.myDate)`.

Comment: I get date and time in console